# Hidden variable declaration VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, variable-declaration

**Question :** Is it possible that the declaration of some variables is "hidden" in VBA ?

**Situation :**

I have an Excel file with lots of modules but for some reasons whenever we open it this message shows up [image] and I tried some "solutions" found on some forums with no success -> I decided to copy sheet by sheet and module by module the whole thing in a new "clean" excel file.

**Issue :** A code doesn't run saying that variable XXX is not declared (ok...makes sense), but I checked in the corrupted file and even though it is not declared anywhere neither (I checked with the Finder in the whole project) the code in question can run...Confusing !

Any explanations for this ?

Comment: If a variable isn't declared but is used then it is created late as a variant, if option explicit isn't present then it is accepted usage (not best practice though). It is likely that the old workbook did not have option explicit whereas the new one does.

Comment: @Zerk : YES . I totally fogot this detail. You're right ! I just checked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Worst case, quick and dirty scenario** - remove `Option Explicit` from each module, class, workbook and worksheet. It makes sure, that all variables are declared. E.g., try running the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()
    k = 5
    Debug.Print k

End Sub
```

You cannot. Then add `dim k as long` after `Sub TestMe()`. Or remove the `Option Explicit`. Now you can run it.

**Slow and clean solution:** Check all variables, which are highlighted when you try to run the code and declare them. Your code would run faster.

Comment: Slow and clean solution IS the solution ... your answer is the wrong way around?

Comment: Well, if you have 50.000 lines of code and a deadline in 30 minutes, you can risk it a bit. @whytheq

Comment: Yeah it's simply way better to add it. It prevents spelling mistakes from being unseen also. I already set the _Require variable Declaration_ option a while ago but this one wasn't done by me that's why.

Comment: Better to push the deadline back and get a correct result, rather than stick to the deadline and lose billions due to a misplaced decimal point.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook not another xl related World economic meltdown .... Seb: BE CAREFUL!